# Error at compiled time in Chrome driver code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have used this code in MyEclipse for Chrome driver..

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\selenium\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0.zip\chromedriver.exe");
```

But found compiled time error that:

`'Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

But path that I have given is correct.

How can I sort this error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
D:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0.zip\\chromedriver.exe
```

instead of

```
D:\selenium\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0.zip\chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting this property, you can set the PATH env variable pointing to the directory of the Chrome Driver, so that you don't require code changes once you move code on to other machine